# How to change URL on scroll?

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am looking for a way to change the URL to a different page on my site once the site detects that the user has scrolled. (In JavaScript)

I'm a designer so not super into code, would anyone be able to help or have any ideas?

I found "}object.onscroll = function(){myScript};" as a piece of code that detects scrolls (I think?).

Any help would be massively appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

you would want to use

```
window.addEventListener(‘scroll’, () => {
window.location.href = “google.com”
});
```

But why would you want to do this? This would be really bad UX for the user. unless your site is some kind of game or something.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help!
I am building a site on Wix that doesn't support scroll actions without using code. When a page changes, specific animations trigger, hard to explain without showing you really but it *should* be fit for its purpose.

Gunna test it out though

Comment: Well hopefully it works, you might actually want to find a different thing to bind it to, not sure if window is the best, that was just me quickly writing out what you’d want to do.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to redirect when element in viewport.

```js
function isInViewport(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <=
            (window.innerHeight ||
                document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <=
            (window.innerWidth ||
                document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    )
}

const someElement = document.querySelector('#element')
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (isInViewport(someElement)) {
        window.location.href = "URL"
    }
})
```